# Is there an easy way to toggle background position between two states on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a drop down price list broken down into bite size chunks for easier viewing, there are several services being offered and some services break down into sub-categories, the user can click on a button with a little arrow pointing down, on clicking the button another level of sub categories is slideToggle revealed. The arrow button stays at the bottom so that they can hide the sub categories when ready.

I was hoping to change the arrow from pointing down when hiding sub-categories, to up when showing them. I already have an image prepared with both arrow states in one `png`, I just need a command/set of commands that will toggle the arrow between states when hiding/showing the sub categories.

The arrow lies within this HTML as a background image for the `.arrows` div.

```
<div class="morebutton" id="firstarrow">

    <div class="arrows">

    </div>

</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.morebutton{
width:220px;
height:8px;
border:outset 1px #ddd;
/*margin-bottom:5px;*/
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:0px;
background:#ddd;
border-radius:25px;
cursor:pointer;
overflow:hidden;
}

.morebutton:hover{
background:#eee;
height:15px;        
}

.arrows{
width:20px;
height:15px;
margin:0px auto;
background:url(images/morearrows.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
```

This is the current jQuery on the elements:

```
$("#firstarrow").click(function(){
    $("#londonmore").slideToggle(100);
});
//this reveals the sub-categories in a table called #londonmore
```

Here's what I have tried (within the function above):

```
$(this).toggle( 
    function(){ 
        $(".arrows").css({"background-position":"0px"}); 
    },  
    function(){ 
        $(".arrows").css({"background-position":"10px"}); 
});
```

I have tried playing about with the amounts the background position changes but all it does is move the arrow slightly, it doesn't move it on the first click and doesn't move to the position I want it in, also it doesn't move back on hiding the sub-categories.

[image: Sub-Categories Hidden. Arrow Facing Down.]

[image: Sub-Categories Showing. Arrow Should Be Facing Up.]

Comment: Yes, it's easy. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Just toggle the source of the button you are using !!

Comment: @Dominic: People wont generally write code for you. If on the other hand you post the code you have tried with an explanation of what you are trying to do and where it seems to go wrong they will help you out... again: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: The key problem in your code is that you are only sending a single background-position value... you must send both. That said see my answer for a better way to implement with reusable css and js.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggling background position on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625508/toggling-background-position-on-click)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is going to have to be a bit general as you haven't posted any code yet, but there is a callback you get on [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/). Use that to do the [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

You'll just have to check which state you're in so you set the right arrow.

For example:

```
    $('#button1').slideToggle('slow',function() {
        if ( ... ) {
            $('#arrow1').css('background-position','?px ?px');
        } else {
            $('#arrow1').css('background-position','?px ?px');
        }
    });
```

You'll have to fill in the blanks - or you could implement the callback in another way, but whatever you do if you want to do the css change when the slideToggle fires, using the callback is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldnt modify the background directly via `jQuery.css`. Id just toggle a CSS class instead. Im not sure what your markup looks like but for the sake of an example lets do it this way:

```
<div class="expandable">
  <a href="#" class="expandable-expander">
    <span class="arrows">This is our arrow element</span>
  </a>
  <div class="expandable-content">
      <p>This is the content to expand!</p>
      <p>This is the content to expand!</p>
      <p>This is the content to expand!</p>
      <p>This is the content to expand!</p>
      <p>This is the content to expand!</p>
      <p>This is the content to expand!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then we can do this css:

```
.arrows {
  /* this is the default state and as the default we want the arrow closed
     so the bg position 0 0 is for the closed state */
  width:20px;
  height:15px;
  margin:0px auto;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f00 url(images/morearrows.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  text-indent: -999em;
}
.expandable {
  width:220px;
}
.expandable .expandable-expander {
   display: block;
   background: #ccc;
   width:220px;
   height:8px;
   border:outset 1px #ddd;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   margin-top:0px;
   background:#ddd;
   border-radius:25px;
   cursor:pointer;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.expandable .expandable-content {

   /* content is hidden at first unles .expandable is also .open */
    display: none;
}

.expandable.open .expandable-content {
   display: block;
}

.expandable .expandable-expander:hover {
   background:#eee;
   height:15px;
}

.expandable.open .expandable-expander .arrows {
   background-position: 0 -10px;
   /* only change the background position because everything else is set up */
    background-color: #0f0;
}
```

And then finally our jQuery based js:

```
$(function(){
   $('.expandable .expandable-expander').click(function (e) {
       var $this = $(this),
           $container = $this.closest('.expandable'),
           $content = $container.find('.expandable-content');
       e.preventDefault();

       $content.slideToggle(100, function () {
           $container.toggleClass('open');
       });
   });
});
```

By doing this way and configuring things based on self contained structures you only need to run this code once on any given page and as long as you use conforming class structure youll be fine. You can reuse it in a number of places without changing much of any thing.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tNwss/)

Word of caution... unless you can ensure the state of the DOM you might want to avoid toggle functions and use the long hand versions. If something gets out of sync you may be toggling somethings open while toggling other things closed. I dotn think it will be an issue in this case though.

Comment: This is an incredibly confusing solution, I agree now that toggling the class is the best way to go but I haven't a clue why I have to add so much code to do so. Also it doesn't actually do what I want, could you maybe tell me how to toggle an element between two classes on click event, in a far simpler example like the one above. +1 for effort and time spent to help me, but unfortunately it isn't the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry i had some mispelled class names.. updated the fiddle, code in the question will update momentarily. Also not since i dont have a background sprite avialable I have jsut changed the background color of the thing that would contain your arrows...

Comment: Updated code does exactly what I'm looking for, its just an awful lot of code to implement for such a tedious effect. I will accept as correct answer if I can't find a simpler solution, thankyou.

Comment: `tedious` is kind of the point. The way you were doign it you would have had to write the same event attachment for each expandable area you had (based off ID's), and then do that on all the different pages where you use them. This way you simply add the css once, and include that js snippet once on the page where you use them. and then just make sure youre markup matches.

Comment: With that said the code you tried in your question should work... you just need to make sure you provide `0 10px` for your background-position call. Thats why its not working.

Comment: Its even more tedious than you can imagine because I only need this to work on two arrow buttons, which are part of the template that loads the same on every page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17147/discussion-between-dominic-b-c-and-prodigitalson)