# Toggling background position on click

Tags: jquery, toggle, background-position

I am trying to achieve this [Is there an easy way to toggle background position between two states on click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573432/is-there-an-easy-way-to-toggle-background-position-between-two-states-on-click-e)

I have constructed a function that *should* work.. haven't got a clue why it won't. I have spent a number of hours trying to achieve this for such a tedious part of my project, but it's necessary.

Please take a look at this function:

```
$("#secondarrow").click(function(){
    /*$(".arrows").toggle( 
    function(){ 
        $(this).css({"background-position":"0px 0px"}); 
    },  
    function(){ 
        $(this).css({"background-position":"0px -30px"}); 
    });*/
    /*$(".arrows").toggleClass(function() {
    if ($(this).is(".arrows")) {
    return ".arrowsup";
    } else {
    return ".arrows";
    }
    });*/
    $('#secondarrow').toggle(function() { 
    $("#arrow2").css('backgroundPosition', '0px -15px'); 
    }, function() { 
    $("#arrow2").css('backgroundPosition', '0px 0px'); 
    });
$("#ukmore").slideToggle(100);
$("#clause").slideToggle(100);
});
```

What it should do is, on clicking the div name second arrow, it reveals a number of sub-categories and *at the same time* toggle the background position of a div child with the id #arrow2 from an arrow that's pointing down (to indicate *click to reveal more*) to an arrow that's pointing up which is part of the same background image (to indicate *click to hide sub-categories*).

I have tried a number of different function structures but none of them are working as required, the latest one - the one that isn't commented out - does change the background position to show the arrow pointing up but it only does it the on the first click AND only does it when clicking directly on the #arrow1 div, when I need it to toggle back and forth on clicking the #secondarrow div.

Please help.

Comment: maybe a dumb question but shouldn't it be "background-position" instead of "backgroundPosition"? also could you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: @Antimated Don't worry I ask silly questions like that all the time, you don't know if you don't ask. Nope, it's fine - I believe that's the correct jQuery syntax for it, but it can be either. If you check out the previous question there is plenty to give context to my question including images and some solutions that don't work.

Comment: you said _a div child with the id #arrow1_ and you use the class selector for it (.arrow1). Try changing that

Comment: @AndreiR Sorry yes I spotted that and changed it just after I posted, still didn't work. Have edited the code in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all - you need to practise handling events a bit more.

`.toggle` is also an event handler, so you basically add a new click handler for toggling when the item is clicked.

You only need to do something like this:

```
$("#secondarrow").toggle(function() { 
    $("#arrow2").css('backgroundPosition', '0px -15px');
    //do more stuff on first click
    }, function() { 
    $("#arrow2").css('backgroundPosition', '0px 0px'); 
    //do more stuff on second click
    });
```

I can't check if the above will work for you. I recommend putting your code in jsFiddle for stackoverflow question too.

**Second thing**

It is better to create a css class with the second position and then bind a click event in which you toggle the class:

```
$("#secondarrow").click(function(){
   $("#arrow2").toggleClass('position2');
})
```

And a tip:

Use firebug or chrome developer tools to debug your code. You can check if your selector was correct.
Also,read about selector caching, eg. `$element=$('.something'); $element.show()`

Comment: Thankyou! The second thing is the elegant solution I've been looking for. Others suggested a very similar course of action, and I already had a separate class ready, just needed that key ingredient. I knew the solution didn't have to be 5+ lines of code. Also, thankyou for the advice, I'm continuously learning and welcome it.

Comment: I'm always happy to see people wanting to learn. You would benefit a lot from a 4hour intensive course on jquery to kickstart your self-learning. Try looking for free courses from student organizations. I've done some free courses for students where I live. I guess there are more people who do that.

Comment: That would be useful, although I also study business at uni and programming is second priority, so I study it in my spare time on the web. It can be frustrating sifting through old and unhelpful resources though, so it's great when I find good ones. Stack Overflow is such a great resource.

Comment: I'm not putting any pressure on you. I just said you'd save a lot of time if someone showed you a few things to begin with. Anyway - just keep having fun! Good luck

Comment: I finally took an intensive JS/jQuery course with AppendTo, now I can read and write functions :) I was such a noob before.